# Need more performant hex2bytes bytes2hex encoding/decoding

Tags: c++, openssl, hex, aes

I write an encryption library which uses AES256 CBC based on openssl (libcrypto.so). My library is written in C++ (C++11, actually)
Profiling with valgrind shows, that the encryption/decryption is very fast, but my encoding/decoding of the resulting bytes to a hex string is slow.

When encrypting, *encode_bytes2hex* needs 50% of the total program runtime. When decrypting *decode_hex2bytes* needs even 75% of the total runtime.
I want at least have *decode_hex2bytes* to be as fast as *encode_bytes2hex*. But it would also be nice to decrease their runtime by factor 10 or so. I expect these "little" functions to use only insignificant parts of the total runtime.

Here are my implementations:

```
std::string encode_bytes2hex(const std::vector<unsigned char>& rData){
  //encode as hex 
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  for (auto& c : rData)
  {
      ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c);
  }
  return ss.str();
}

std::vector<unsigned char> decode_hex2bytes(const std::string& rHex){
  std::vector<unsigned char> oBytes(rHex.length()/2);
  std::stringstream ssConv;
  for(size_t n = 0; n < rHex.length(); n+=2)
  {
      ssConv << std::hex << rHex.substr(n,2);
      int byte;
      ssConv >> byte;
      oBytes[n/2] = byte & 0xFF;
      ssConv.str(std::string());
      ssConv.clear();
  }
  return oBytes;
}
```

I guess removing std::stringstream somehow could speed-up everything a lot. But how?

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Did you enable the compilers optimizer?

Comment: This does not look like an efficient way of doing something that should be utterly trivial. No `substr` or `setfill` required. You have the right idea with pre-sizing the output string or vector, but from there the more direct approach is to `switch` on the bytes, or just check for particular bit patterns to detect  `0`..`9` vs. `a` to `f` or `A` to `F`.

Comment: A simple lookup table should do the job nicely and be quite efficient.

Comment: If you're calling this so many times that it's using 50% of your CPU - I'd suggest you just make it a lookup table.  You know there's only 255 options, make a map and just look it up.

Comment: To be honest, i just copied the functions from SO, tested them and did not think of it any further. Some weeks later, i observed them to be the bottle neck. I will try an implementation with a map and post my results. Also the hint to turn on optimizer flags for gcc is valuable. After short reading i see they are not enabled by default

Comment: bin2hex needs a 16-byte LUT, but hex2bin takes a 256-byte LUT; make sure to mark the wrong characters in 2nd LUT. The return type should be `pair<vector<uint8_t>, size_t>` to report the number of correct characters. The inputs to functions better be `span<uint8_t>`(bin2hex) and `string_view`(hex2bin) - rather than reference to `vector` and `string`; this increases genericness and optimization, without using templates or paying any runtime costs. `iostream` should definitely be avoided.

Comment: what do you mean with correct characters? I want to decode any bytes, not just valid ascii chars? Regarding string_view: I am on C++11, maybe C++14 next year. C++17 is like lightyears away :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers of @Toby Speight and @Pepijn Kramer I could create much faster functions.
This is my solution for C++11

```
constexpr char to_hex1(unsigned char c) {
    return "0123456789abcdef"[c/16];
};

constexpr char to_hex2(unsigned char c) {
    return "0123456789abcdef"[c%16];
};

std::string encode_bytes2hex(const std::vector<unsigned char>& rData)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(rData.size() * 2);

    for (auto c: rData) {
        result.push_back(to_hex1(c));
        result.push_back(to_hex2(c));
    }
    return result;
}

constexpr unsigned char from_hex(char nC) {

    return (nC >= '0' && nC <= '9') ? (nC - '0') : 
            ((nC >= 'a' && nC <= 'f') ? (nC - 'a' +10u) : 
            (nC >= 'A' && nC <= 'F') ? (nC - 'A' +10u) : 
            nC 
            );
};

std::vector<unsigned char> decode_hex2bytes(const std::string& rHex)
{
    if (rHex.size() % 2) {
         throw std::invalid_argument("hex string of odd length");
    }
    std::vector<unsigned char> oResult;
    oResult.reserve(rHex.size()/2);

    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < rHex.size();  i += 2) {
        oResult.push_back(from_hex(rHex[i]) * 16u + from_hex(rHex[i+1]));
    }
    return oResult;
}
```

I had to write `from_hex` in a disgusting way, because C++11 does only allow `constexpr` functions with nothing than a return statement. For C++14 and newer it is possible to write cleaner code.
But I must say, even with this code these functions are much much much slower than the AES encryption/decryption routines in openssl itsself. (In my problem I encrypt a string, then encode the bytes to hex).

Including the `-O3` parameter for gcc I could speed up my decryption throughput from approx 80k per second to 475k per second. This is a 6x speed-up. The encryption is now up from 175k to 475k which is a speed-up of approx 3x.

Comment: Note that C++ does guarantee the meaning of `nC - '0'`, but not of `nC - 'a' +10u` nor of `nC - 'A' +10u`.  You might be willing to assume your target character set has `abcdef` and `ABCDEF` represented by consecutive characters, but it's worth a comment in the code warning about that assumption.

Comment: `nC-'0'` is just shorthand for `nC - 48u`. So I rely on the Standardization of ASCII. I dont understand, why you say, this not guaranteed by C++?

Comment: Because C++ doesn't require the character coding to be one of the ASCII codings.  Your code works on ASCII systems, but not necessarily on others.  The only guarantee that C++ makes about character values is that `0123456789` have consecutive values (which is why `nc - '0'` is okay, but the other two expressions are not).

Answer (score 4):

You're incurring a lot of unnecessary overhead when you go via `std::stringstream`, and an additional copy when you go to/from a `std::string`.

Just work with the string directly, and read/write each nibble in a loop of your own:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string encode_bytes2hex(const std::vector<unsigned char>& rData)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(rData.size() * 2);

    static auto const to_hex = [](unsigned char c) {
        return "0123456789abcdef"[c];
    };
    for (auto c: rData) {
        result.push_back(to_hex(c / 16));
        result.push_back(to_hex(c % 16));
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> decode_hex2bytes(const std::string& rHex)
{
    if (rHex.size() % 2) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("hex string of odd length");
    }
    std::vector<unsigned char> result;
    result.reserve(rHex.size()/2);

    static auto const from_hex = [](char c) {
        switch (c) {
        case '0': return 0; case '1': return 1; case '2': return 2;
        case '3': return 3; case '4': return 4; case '5': return 5;
        case '6': return 6; case '7': return 7; case '8': return 8;
        case '9': return 9;

        case 'a': return 10; case 'b': return 11; case 'c': return 12;
        case 'd': return 13; case 'e': return 14; case 'f': return 15;

        case 'A': return 10; case 'B': return 11; case 'C': return 12;
        case 'D': return 13; case 'E': return 14; case 'F': return 15;
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument("not a hex digit");
    };

    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < rHex.size();  i += 2) {
        result.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>(from_hex(rHex[i]) * 16u + from_hex(rHex[i+1])));
    }
    return result;
}
```

This passes the same tests:

```
int main()
{
    const auto v = std::vector<unsigned char>{ 0xFF, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x12 };
    const auto s = std::string{"ff0a0012"};

    return encode_bytes2hex(v) != s
        || decode_hex2bytes(s) != v;
}
```

N.B. Any decent compiler will optimise the big `switch`, probably into a lookup table (or whatever is best on the target architecture).

Comment: Your solution did speed-up my complete code by approx 100% (e.g. I can now encrypt/decrypt twice as much per second). The additional optimization flag for g++ -O3 did increased the through-put by another approx 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a lookup table first so you can skip a lot of the recurring calculations. (constexpr is really nice for this).
Also the calculation loop is branchless which can help too (if you know your input is always right you can remove the checks)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

// creata a lookup table at compile time
// will fit in cache so very fast at runtime
static std::array<std::uint8_t, 256> value_map = []
{
    std::array<std::uint8_t, 256> lookup{};
    for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c) lookup[c] = (c - '0');
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'f'; ++c) lookup[c] = (c - 'a' + 10);
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'F'; ++c) lookup[c] = (c - 'A' + 10);
    return lookup;
}();

// check for input of 1 correct character
constexpr bool is_valid_hex_char(char c)
{
    return ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) || ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'f')) || ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'F'));
}

// check for correct input string 
constexpr bool is_valid_hex_str(std::string_view sv)
{
    return std::all_of(sv.begin(), sv.end(), is_valid_hex_char);
}

std::vector<std::uint8_t> to_hex(std::string_view sv)
{
    // check preconditions (NEVER trust your input)
    // empty and odd length strings will not be valid
    // nor will strings containing non hex characters
    if ((sv.length() == 0) || ((sv.length() % 2) != 0) || !is_valid_hex_str(sv))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument{ "incorrect input string" };
    };

    // we know the size of the output vector so pre-allocate
    // makes sure all values are 0 too
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> values(sv.size() / 2ul, 0);

    // i = index in output vector
    // n = index in input string
    for (std::size_t i = 0, n = 0; n < sv.length(); ++i, n += 2)
    {
        // lookup 2 characters in one go
        // the first character will contribute times 16 (shift left by 4)
        values[i] |= (value_map[sv[n]] << 4); 
        values[i] |= value_map[sv[n + 1]];
    }

    return values;
}

int main()
{
    auto values = to_hex("102132A0B1C2");
        
    for(const auto v : values)
    {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(v);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Careful with that character arithmetic - C++ guarantees that `0`..`9` are consecutive, but makes no such warranty for letters.

Comment: Also, slicing characters down to `std::uint8_t` may be risky, even if that (optional) type is provided.

Comment: I wanted to test your version, but string_view is C++17. I use C++11 (due to pre-defined build chain)

Comment: Hmm I don't have C++11 anywhere anymore but this is a version that compiles with C++14 (and I think it will on C++11 too). https://onlinegdb.com/FUAZvEH-5